# Why is my MySQL query returning wrong data with IN values

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query in PHP and I am getting to many results.  Here is the query:

```
mysql> SELECT `location` FROM `listings` WHERE `fulltext` LIKE '%a%' OR `title` LIKE
'%a%' AND location IN(33702,33709,33714,33716,33760,33762,33771,33773,33777,33781,33782)
ORDER BY `date` DESC \g
```

and this is the CMD result that I get, which matches exactly what I am getting in the PHP run:

```
+----------+
| location |
+----------+
|    78787 |
|    33782 |
|    33782 |
|    98102 |
|    33782 |
|    33782 |
|    33782 |
|    33782 |
|    33782 |
|    56564 |
|    44569 |
|    33782 |
|    33782 |
+----------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, I should not be getting 78787,98102,56564 or 44569.  does anyone see what could be wrong with the query.  Let me know if you need more info.

P.S. I originally had this set up to use RLIKE, and it will be again once I get this figured out.

Comment: Two words: operator precedence

Comment: group your `OR` condition eg. `WHERE (\`fulltext\` LIKE ..... OR title LIKE ...) AND  location IN ()`

Comment: Thank you all so much...  Parens worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the precedence of your `OR` is incorrect. Try:

```
SELECT `location` FROM `listings` WHERE (`fulltext` LIKE '%a%' OR `title` LIKE '%a%') AND location IN(33702,33709,33714,33716,33760,33762,33771,33773,33777,33781,33782) ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

The important thing here is to use brackets to separate your two basic conditions:

1. check `title` OR `fulltext`
2. check location

Comment: Geniuses, every one of you...  Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [operator precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html), your query is being processed like this:

```
SELECT `location`
FROM `listings`
WHERE `fulltext` LIKE '%a%'
  OR (
       `title` LIKE '%a%'
    AND LOCATION IN(33702,33709,33714,33716,33760,33762,33771,33773,33777,33781,33782)
  )
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Which I don't think is what you want. Try adding parenthesis where you want to cause the proper evaluation of the `WHERE` clause.